# css transform doing odd things on firefox

Tags: css, firefox

Something annoyed me about this button I just made, the text appears to move just slightly in regards to the button body using `translate:transform`. Am I hallucinating?

```css
.clicky1:active { 
    margin-bottom:-2px;
 margin-top:2px;
}

.clicky2:active { 
    transform:translate(0px, 2px);
}

.butt { 
    padding:20px;
    display:flex;
 justify-content:center;
 align-items:center;
    
    font-size:30px;
    
    background-color:rgb(240,240,240);
    border:1px solid black;
} .butt:hover {
    background-color:white;   
}

.cont {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-around;
    align-items:center;
    
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
    <div class="butt clicky1">button1</div>
    <div class="butt clicky2">button2</div>
</div>
```

Only appears on firefox, not in chrome.

If I'm not crazy, how could I get around it without resorting to using margin (since its supposed to be a generic class and I have other uses for margin depending on context)?

Comment: Cannot replicate in FF40.0.2

Comment: I am also using 40.0.2, its very slight, the text should appear to move left and down by like 1px in relation to the box

Comment: Sorry..not seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

I see it, but I think it is just a visual anomaly in the way FF is rendering the text when the element uses translate (possibly a bug). I noticed that the strange text rendering phenomenon would disappear when I changed Firefox's page zoom level as well as at different browser widths.

I posted a snippet answer below that uses `position:relative;` and `top:2px;` to accomplish what you are doing with the translate and without messing with margins. It appears to render the text as expected, at least in my testing

**Scaled up Screenshot of Strange Text Rendering Phenomenon:**
[image]

**SOLUTION SNIPPET**

```css
.clicky1:active { 
    margin-bottom:-2px;
 margin-top:2px;
}

.clicky2:active { 
    /* Change transform:translate(0px, 2px); to */ top: 2px;
}

.butt { 
    /*add*/position: relative;
    padding:20px;
    display:flex;
 justify-content:center;
 align-items:center;
    
    font-size:30px;
    
    background-color:rgb(240,240,240);
    border:1px solid black;
}

.butt:hover {
    background-color:white;   
}

.cont {
    /*add*/position: relative;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-around;
    align-items:center;
    
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
    <div class="butt clicky1">button1</div>
    <div class="butt clicky2">button2</div>
</div>
```